# Обработка xml в rest запросе

Tags: java, xml, rest, pojo

Веб сервис на Java не может корректно обработать xml. А именно не может прочитать и сформировать значения атрибутов. То есть, такой xml-текст обрабатывается корректно и данные не теряются:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если использовать атрибуты, то их значения не передаются и переменные в pojo классе остаются пустыми, хотя необходимые аннотации использую. Пример xml:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также проблемы с формированием xml-файла. Ожидаемый результат, который я хочу получить от веб-сервиса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фактический результат, который приходит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На передаваемые данные, прошу не обращать никакого внимания)

Исходный код.

Сам веб-сервис:

Test.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/test")
public class Test {
@Autowired
private Dao dao;

@ApiOperation(value = "", response = Response.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "/test-method", method = RequestMethod.POST,
                produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE},
                consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
@ResponseBody
public Response method1(@RequestBody Request request) throws Throwable {
    Response res = dao.method1(request);
    return res;
}

}
```

Dao.java

```
public interface Dao {
    public Response method1(Request request) throws Throwable;
}
```

DaoImpl.java

```
@Service("Test")
@Repository
public class DaoImpl implements Dao {
    final static String SERVICE_NAME = "Test";

public Response method1(Request request) throws Throwable {
    ServiceMain c = new <Result>ServiceMain(SERVICE_NAME, Response.class);    

    /*
    Обработка входящих и исходящих данных
    и
    Работа с БД
    */

    return (Response)c.data;
}

}
```

Initializer.java

```
public class Initializer extends  AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebAppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

SwaggerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build().apiInfo(metaData());
    }   

    private ApiInfo metaData() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("Тест")
                                   .description("Тестовый пример").version("v1.0").build();
    }
}
```

WebAppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("ru.test")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public WebAppConfig() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

Pojo-классы.

Request.java:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Request {
    private String n = null;
    private String v = null;
    private String sync = null;

    public void setN(String n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    public void setV(String v) {
        this.v = v;
    }

    public void setSync(String sync) {
        this.sync = sync;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getN() {
        return n;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getV() {
        return v;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getSync() {
        return sync;
    }
}
```

UpdateItem.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class UpdateItem {
    private String sync = null;
    private String id = null;
    private String kbn = null;
    private String description = null;

    public void setSync(String sync) {
        this.sync = sync;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setKbn(String kbn) {
        this.kbn = kbn;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getSync() {
        return sync;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getKbn() {
        return kbn;
    }

    @XmlValue
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

UpdateItems.java

```
public class UpdateItems {
    private ArrayList<UpdateItem> i = null;

    public void setI(ArrayList<UpdateItem> i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public ArrayList<UpdateItem> getI() {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Response.java

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Response {

    private String sync = null;
    private UpdateItems item = null;
    private String error = null;

    public void setSync(String sync) {
        this.sync = sync;
    }

    public void setItem(UpdateItems item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public void setError(String error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getSync() {
        return sync;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public UpdateItems getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getError() {
        return error;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Правильные pojo файлы, оказывается, должны выглядеть так:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "request", propOrder = {"sync"})
public class Request extends Context {
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String sync = null;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "v")
    protected String v = null;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "n")
    protected String n = null;

    public void setSync(String sync) {
        if(sync == null) { 
            return;
        }

        if(sync.compareTo("null") == 0) { 
            return;
        }

        this.sync = sync;
    }

    public void setV(String v) {
        if(v == null) { 
            return;
        }

        if(v.compareTo("null") == 0) { 
            return;
        }

        this.v = v;
    }

    public void setN(String n) {
        if(n == null) { 
            return;
        }

        if(n.compareTo("null") == 0) { 
            return;
        }

        this.n = n;
    }

    public String getSync() {
        return sync;
    }

    public String getV() {
        return v;
    }

    public String getN() {
        return n;
    }

}
```

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "response", propOrder = {"item", "sync", "error"})
public class Response extends Result {
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private UpdateItems item = null;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String sync = null;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String error = null;

    public void setItem(UpdateItems item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public void setSync(String sync) {
        if(sync == null) { 
            return;
        }

        if(sync.compareTo("null") == 0) { 
            return;
        }

        this.sync = sync;
    }

    public void setError(String error) {
        if(error == null) { 
            return;
        }

        if(error.compareTo("null") == 0) { 
            return;
        }

        this.error = error;
    }

    public UpdateItems getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public String getSync() {
        return sync;
    }

    public String getError() {
        return error;
    }

}
```

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "updateItem", propOrder = {"value"})
public class UpdateItem {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "sync")
    private String sync = null;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    private String id = null;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "kbn")
    private String kbn = null;
    @XmlValue
    private String value = null;

    public void setSync(String sync) {
        if(sync == null) { 
            return;
        }

        if(sync.compareTo("null") == 0) { 
            return;
        }

        this.sync = sync;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        if(id == null) { 
            return;
        }

        if(id.compareTo("null") == 0) { 
            return;
        }

        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setKbn(String kbn) {
        if(kbn == null) { 
            return;
        }

        if(kbn.compareTo("null") == 0) { 
            return;
        }

        this.kbn = kbn;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        if(value == null) { 
            return;
        }

        if(value.compareTo("null") == 0) { 
            return;
        }

        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getSync() {
        return sync;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getKbn() {
        return kbn;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "updateItems", propOrder = {"i"})
public class UpdateItems {
    @XmlElement
    private ArrayList<UpdateItem> i = null;

    public void setI(ArrayList<UpdateItem> i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public ArrayList<UpdateItem> getI() {
        return i;
    }

}
```